# How to go back more than one view model in mvvm light

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I am doing xamarin development and I am not doing forms.

I want to go back by 3 viewcontrollers/activities but goback method is for going back by one viewcontroller or activity

If I use navigateto i believe one more time the viewcontrolller/activity gets added.i.e two instances.

So how to solve this problem ?

**Update:**
*Here is the inavigation interface there is no way to access thr navigational stack as well*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are going back, then use `INavigationService.GoBack();`. You can call that 3 times in a row to go back 3 pages.

```
private void GoBackThree()
{
    _navigationService.GoBack();
    _navigationService.GoBack();
    _navigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: But won't transistion look bad

Comment: Is it possible to cut the transition and make it appear like another one is pushed on top

Comment: Atleast if we could go back 3 times without transition it'd be good

Comment: One more doubt navigateto will add one more instance ....or reuse the existing one kindly clarify

Comment: Yeah The animation will look like it is hopping back. You can implement INavigationService and set the GoBack implementation to fire without animation. Navigation.PopAsync takes a bool param for animating or not. That's about as far as mvvm light goes with its nav service. If you want robust options, you should roll your own Nav service that can take some options for animation or not.

Comment: Thanks ,Is there any guide or examples on how to do that ? If there is any popular thirdparty stuff available , that customizes let me know

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used MVVM Light before but I have quite a bit of experience of Xamarin Forms. I used to use MVVM Cross for navigation but eventually found that the built in Xamarin Forms Navigation was much better, I ran into similar scenarios as to what you have here.

Under the hood it looks like MVVM Light is just wrapping the Xamarin Forms Navigation anyway - http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Flowers/Flowers.Forms/Flowers.Forms/Helpers/NavigationService.cs

I don't think you need give up on MVVM Light navigation but you do need to get under the hood to achieve the navigation without seeing three transitions. I haven't tried this with MVVM Light but it works great with normal Forms navigation.

**Step 1**

Get access to the underlying Xamarin Forms navigation:

```
var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
```

**Step 2**

Remove the two pages you want to skip when navigating back. It's important that you remove them before navigating backwards otherwise you'll get a double transition (note the -2 is because you want to remove the second to last page).

```
var firstPageToRemove = navigation.NavigationStack[navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2];
navigation.RemovePage(firstPageToRemove);

var secondPageToRemove = navigation.NavigationStack[navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2];
navigation.RemovePage(secondPageToRemove);
```

**Step 3**

Navigate backwards

```
_navigationService.GoBack();
```

I hope that works for you.

**Alternative Consideration**

I have a similar application in my app which I've solved a little more elegantly. If you know you never need to be able to navigate back to those previous pages. When you push the new pages on, you can actually remove the previous one if you no longer need it. Please note you have to remove the page **after** you push on the new one otherwise you get two transitions. I use this extension method on-top of the standard Forms Navigation which I showed you how to access in Step 1 to achieve it.

```
public static async Task ReplaceCurrentAsync(this INavigation navigation, Page page, bool animated = false)
{
    var curentPage = navigation.NavigationStack.Last();

    await navigation.PushAsync(page, animated);

    navigation.RemovePage(curentPage);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to acceess the navigational stack in MVVM light

Comment: I know there's no way to access the navigation stack from MVVM light. That's why I gave you the code in step 1 which will access the underlying navigation stack. Did you try the three steps?

Comment: Yes dear ... In view model ... I am getting error "The name application does not exist in the current context" ... In viewcontroller/activity i am getting error "Application does not contain definition for current"